# Signature Capture in PhoneGap Android Application

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am trying to use this 3rd Party Signature Capture Android Application with my PhoneGap Application. I have no idea how to "Call the right Activity" from my PhoneGap App. My Application is written in html and javascript.

Please help!

I have installed the application on my Droid X and it Captures my Signature with my finger. Its super smooth and quick.

http://www.binarysolutions.biz/

Here are the instructions from their website. They are not very detailed.

```
String key      = ""; // set the key, any string you find suitable
String fileName = ""; // set the file name (global write permissions)

Intent intent = new Intent("biz.binarysolutions.signature.CAPTURE");

intent.putExtra(key, fileName);
intent.setComponent(
    new ComponentName(
        "biz.binarysolutions.signature",
        "biz.binarysolutions.signature.Capture"
    )
);

startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
Receiving the result

@Override
protected void onActivityResult
    (
         int    requestCode, 
         int    resultCode, 
         Intent data
    ) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_REQUEST_CODE && 
        resultCode  == RESULT_OK) {

        String fileName = ""; // the same file name as above
        Bitmap bitmap   = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);

        // do with bitmap whatever you like
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integration of the signature application is doable via an `Android Intent` to `invoke` the signature app. Looks like you have the instructions for what you need to do on the *Java* (native) side to integrate with the signature application, but you are at a loss to do so inside a `PhoneGap` Android app.

Take a look at [WebIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662200/phonegap-ios4-x-audio-tag-and-local-files). It is a `PhoneGap` Android plug-in - this is an extension to the `PhoneGap` API and is composed of a small `JavaScript` interface which your `PhoneGap` app uses, and a native (*Java*) component that the `JS` interface talks to. The `WebIntent` blog post linked above actually does a pretty good job of explaining a `PhoneGap` plug-in, too.

What you'll have to do on top of integrating the `WebIntent` plug-in is interfacing the `WebIntent` with the Signature app - so the `intents` getting passed around on the native side contain the proper parameters.

Comment: Can you go into further detail explaining your idea?

Comment: I think you should look into what an Android Intent is (see developer.android.com) and how it fits into the Android architecture. It is a way of invoking an application on an Android device from within another application. This is what you are trying to do. WebIntent is a plugin you can add to your phonegap Android application that will create Android Intents for you. All you need to do is figure out what parameters you have to set in the Intent you want to dispatch to the Signature app. You have all of the instructions posted in your question already, so you're pretty close!

Comment: Fil- I have been studying this for days and purchased a Pro Web Android Apps book (hoping it would better explain the webintent plugin). I am still not getting it. I have a deadline with good client. Any in-depth tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from version 2.5 Signature Capture library can be started from the web browser just by clicking on a specific link. It can also 'upload' captured image to given url. Check out the instructions here:

http://www.binarysolutions.biz/2010/12/signature-capture-for-android.html#usage_web

Hope that could help.

Comment: Can you show me an example of this working? I get an error that the intent is not supported